# How to access Kofax Total Agility from inside .Net forms?

Tags: .net, kofax

I have created a process in Kofax Total Agility. But i am unsure how to access KTA from inside .NET forms.

Is there any supporting document for the same.
I am using version 7.3 of Kofax Total Agility.

Thanks
Chandini

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Start with the API documentation that is shipped with Kofax TotalAgility (default: `http://{servername}/TotalAgility/Help/API_Documentation/latest/index.html`). Kofax also offers an on-demand course for [programming against the KTA API](https://services.kofax.com/training/on-demand.php) that seems to be tailored to what you need.

Apart from that, you can just add references to AgilityServer.*.dll and Agility.Sdk.Model.dll - all of them reside in the installation directory (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Kofax\TotalAgility\Transformation Designer` by default).

Also, you need to modify your App.config file to reflect KTAs service model, endpoints, et cetera - the best place to start is just to copy & paste from one of the existing config files, for example from `Agility.Server.Core.WorkerService.exe.config`.

Here's a small sample that fetches all documents inside a folder using the `CaptureDocumentService`. Change your `sessionid` and `folderid` accordingly:

```
CaptureDocumentService cds = new CaptureDocumentService();
// get all documents in folder
string sessionId = "3F80668AE02E314E860D648BE4CF42AX";
string folderId = "b2def906-f38b-4fe1-8d7e-a7b50081615b";
Folder folder = cds.GetFolder(sessionId, null, folderId);
foreach (Document document in folder.Documents)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ({2}): {1}", document.Id, document.FileName, document.MimeType));
}
```